# Como colocar uma frase dentro de um campo do formulário e ele sumir quando clicar dentro do campo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Gostaria de saber como colocar uma frase dentro de um campo do formulário, e ela sumir quando clicar dentro do campo.

Tem como ser em CSS? Em que se faz isso?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Existe uma propriedade no HTML5 chamada `placeholder` que faz examente o que você quer.

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Digite seu nome" />
```

Comment: muito obrigado! Funcionou 100%

Comment: Simples e certeiro !

Answer (score 1):

Pode utilizar o placeholder, como foi dito, ou utilizar js e limpar o campo sempre que clicar nele.

```
<input type="text" id="input" value="Value" onClick="func()"/>
<script>
    var func= function(){
        var elem = document.getElementById("input");
        elem.value = "";
    }
</script>
```